How to dynamically build a query to build JSON object in PL/pgSQL?
I am building a function to insert a record into an audit table every time a record is inserted, updated, or deleted in the parent table.
I am struggling to insert one JSON object that is the primary keys of the parent table and their values. The parent table must have primary keys, but the number of primary keys varies. The goal is to have this JSON object be a unique identifier for the parent row in the audit table so we can prune up to the last X number of operations per record in the parent table.
Parent table:
CREATE TABLE parent_table (
    id int4 NOT NULL,
    textfield text NULL,
    id2 int4 NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT test_audit_table_pk PRIMARY KEY (id,id2)
);

CREATE TRIGGER t_insert_upate_delete AFTER INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE ON
    parent_table FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION audit.audit_trigger();

INSERT INTO parent_table(id, id2, textfield)
VALUES (9, 10, 'TODAY');

Working pl/pgsql in the trigger function
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION audit_trigger()
    RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    SECURITY DEFINER
AS $function$
DECLARE
        audit_table_schema VARCHAR = 'audit';
        audit_table_name VARCHAR = TG_TABLE_SCHEMA || '__' || TG_TABLE_NAME || '_history';
        audit_index_name VARCHAR = audit_table_name || '_etl_modified_timestamp_idx';
        stmt VARCHAR;
BEGIN
-- Execute a CREATE IF NOT EXISTS statement for the audit table
        EXECUTE format($$
            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %1$I.%2$I (
                tabname text NULL,
                schemaname text NULL,
                operation text NULL,
                new_val jsonb NULL,
                old_val jsonb NULL,
                updated_cols text NULL,
                primary_keys jsonb NULL, -- INSERTING INTO THIS ROW IS MY ISSUE
                etl_modified_timestamp timestamptz NULL)$$,
                audit_table_schema, audit_table_name);

    IF TG_OP = 'INSERT' THEN
        -- This is the query that needs to be updated to also insert one JSON object of the parent table's primary keys and their values into the `primary_keys` column of the audit table. 
        -- Expected JSON object to insert would take the form {"id": 9, "id2": 10}
        stmt = format($$
                INSERT INTO %1$I.%2$I (
                    tabname,
                    schemaname,
                    operation,
                    new_val,
                    -- primary_keys, Can't get this to work
                    etl_modified_timestamp
                )
                VALUES ($1, $2, $3, TO_JSONB($4),CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)$$, audit_table_schema, audit_table_name);

    ELSIF TG_OP = 'UPDATE' AND akeys(hstore(NEW.*) - hstore(OLD.*)) != akeys(hstore('')) THEN
        -- Simiar INSERT statement
        RETURN NULL;

    ELSIF TG_OP = 'DELETE' THEN
        -- Similar INSERT statement
        RETURN NULL;
    END IF;

    EXECUTE stmt USING TG_TABLE_NAME, TG_TABLE_SCHEMA, TG_OP, NEW, OLD;

    RETURN NULL;

END;
$function$
;

This pl/pgsql code works to extract the primary keys and loop over them:
    determine_pks_stmt = $$
        SELECT kcu.column_name AS pk
        FROM
            information_schema.table_constraints tc
        JOIN
            information_schema.key_column_usage kcu
        ON
            tc.constraint_name = kcu.constraint_name
        AND tc.table_schema = kcu.table_schema
        WHERE
            tc.constraint_type = 'PRIMARY KEY'
        AND tc.table_name = $1
        AND tc.table_schema = $2
    $$; 
    RAISE NOTICE 'determine_pks_stmt: %', determine_pks_stmt;

    FOR pks IN EXECUTE determine_pks_stmt USING TG_TABLE_NAME, TG_TABLE_SCHEMA
    LOOP
        RAISE NOTICE 'pks.pk: %', pks.pk;
        -- But how do I build up the query statement to extract the JSON here?
    END LOOP; 

Failed efforts:
json_pks_stmt VARCHAR = '';

FOR pks IN EXECUTE determine_pks_stmt USING TG_TABLE_NAME, TG_TABLE_SCHEMA

LOOP
-- Goal is to create something like this which normally works in SQL
-- json_build_object('id', new_val->'id', 'id2', new_val->'id2')
    
    IF counter != 0 THEN 
        json_pks_stmt = json_pks_stmt || ', ' ;
    END IF;
    
    json_pks_stmt = json_pks_stmt || pks.pk || ', ' || TO_JSONB(NEW)-> || pks.pk ;
    counter = counter + 1;
    
END LOOP; 
json_pks_stmt = json_pks_stmt || ')';

But I'm struggling with syntax errors - thank you

And the syntax errors are?

Various depending on how I was trying the statement: but this one is SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: operator does not exist: || information_schema.sql_identifier

The errors are probably in my failed json_pks_stmt = statement

||  is for string concatenation and  TO_JSONB(NEW) is producing a  jsonb type so that is not going to work.

Sure, that makes sense - how can I do what I'm trying to do then? Use '%', TO_JSONB(NEW) instead?

See a post I did some years ago Postgres and JSON for some ideas.

poor question. share data @jryan14ify

I have an INSERT VALUES statement in the top SQL block. That's all the data that is needed to describe the problem @ArtBindu

I never found out how to make it work with jsonb, but switched to using hstore column type instead and built up a string convertible to hstore.
DECLARE
        audit_table_schema VARCHAR = 'audit';
        audit_table_name VARCHAR = TG_TABLE_SCHEMA || '__' || TG_TABLE_NAME || '_history';
        stmt VARCHAR;
        determine_pks_stmt VARCHAR;
        pks RECORD;
        hstore_pks_stmt TEXT = '';
        counter INTEGER = 0;

BEGIN
FOR pks IN EXECUTE determine_pks_stmt USING TG_TABLE_NAME, TG_TABLE_SCHEMA

LOOP
    IF counter != 0 THEN 
        hstore_pks_stmt = hstore_pks_stmt || ', ' ;
    END IF;
    
    hstore_pks_stmt = hstore_pks_stmt || pks.pk || '=>' || cast(TO_JSONB(NEW)->pks.pk AS text) ;
    counter = counter + 1;
END LOOP; 

stmt = format($$
        INSERT INTO %1$I.%2$I (
            tabname,
            schemaname,
            operation,
            new_val,
            primary_keys, 
            etl_modified_timestamp
        )
        VALUES (
            $1,
            $2,
            $3,
            TO_JSONB($4),
            $6::hstore, 
            CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
        )$$, audit_table_schema, audit_table_name);

EXECUTE stmt USING TG_TABLE_NAME, TG_TABLE_SCHEMA, TG_OP, NEW, OLD, hstore_pks_stmt;

Disadvantages

hstore only stores and represents values as text rather than other data types (such as int)
Querying the hstore column uses a different syntax than the existing jsonb columns


You seem to be looking for
json_pks_stmt = (
    SELECT 'json_build_object(' || string_agg(format('%1$L, NEW.%1$I', kcu.column_name), ', ') || ')'
    FROM information_schema.table_constraints tc
    JOIN information_schema.key_column_usage kcu ON tc.constraint_name = kcu.constraint_name AND tc.table_schema = kcu.table_schema
    WHERE tc.constraint_type = 'PRIMARY KEY'
      AND tc.table_name = TG_TABLE_NAME
      AND tc.table_schema = TG_TABLE_SCHEMA
);

that will build an SQL expression like json_build_object('id', NEW.id, 'id2', NEW.id2).
